# React native TextField update

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to fill in the inputs with my data from the database and make changes to it. When I fill in the inputs there is no problem but when I want to edit I have a problem. The data is static and does not depend on any variable. How can I solve this problem? I shared the codes below.

RN 0,62

Update codes.

```js
  const [banners, setBanners] = React.useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        Axios.post(props.GlobalStates.baseURL + "mobile/mobile_events.php", { request: "mobile", action: "getallbanners" }).then(response => {
            setBanners(response.data);
        })
    }, [])
    function changeBannerStatus(e, item) {
        Axios.post(props.GlobalStates.baseURL + "mobile/mobile_events.php", {
            request: "mobile",
            action: "editbanner",
            id: item.id,
            content: item.content,
            header: item.header,
            status: e
        }).then(response => {
            setBanners(response.data);
        })
    }
    function changeBannerHeader(e, index) {
        banners[index].header += e;
        setBanners(banners);
    }
    function changeBannerContent(e, index) {
        banners[index].content += e;
        setBanners(banners);
    }
    return (
        <Layout style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Header />
            <FlatList
                data={banners}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
                    <Layout style={{ width: "95%", flexDirection: "column", padding: 15, borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10, margin: 10 }}>
                        <Layout>
                            <Switch
                                trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: "#81b0ff" }}
                                thumbColor={item.status == 1 ? "#DD5347" : "#f4f3f4"}
                                ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
                                onValueChange={(e) => {
                                    changeBannerStatus(e, item);
                                }}
                                value={item.status == 1 ? true : false}
                            ></Switch>
                        </Layout>
                        <Layout style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
                            <Input value={item.header} onChangeText={(e) => {
                                changeBannerHeader(e, index)
                            }}>
                            </Input>
                        </Layout>
                        <Layout style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
                            <Input value={item.content} onChangeText={(e) => {
                                changeBannerContent(e, index)
                            }}>
                            </Input>
                        </Layout>
                        <Image source={{ uri: props.GlobalStates.baseURL + item.image }} style={{ width: "100%", height: 100 }}></Image>
                    </Layout>
                }
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
        </Layout>

    );
```

Comment: You need to copy your data into a temporary object, then modify it and when saved save it into the database.

Comment: I know this method but i have a array value and 10 15 element. For any element update i have to define lots of temporrary const. 
maybe there is a healthier solution.

Comment: Well, you'll have to store the data somewhere at some point, even if you don't know about it. Regarding the healthiest solution, I'd suggest looking into Redux, since it forces you into writing your code in a way that will make fetching, modifying and reuploading data way easier and harder to mess up.

Comment: Thank you dude. In the use here, I think there is no difference between using variable definition with useState and my Redux global variable definition. I have to find a different method.